# Substring function in where clause eating CPU time

Tags: sql, db2

Can I rearrange the below query in any other form?

```
SELECT
    ELIG_TYP
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE COMPANY_CD IN 
    (SELECT SUBSTR(CMPNYID, 1, 4) FROM TABLE2 WHERE USR = 'Badshah')
```

Comment: The ideal situation would be to join the company fields on the two tables directly, without needing to resort to substring operations.  As it stands now, I don't think you can use an index for such a join.  You might want to consider changing the design of `TABLE2` such that a direct join becomes possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim

Comment: my code doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do using join:

```
SELECT  ELIG_TYP
FROM    TABLE1
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.COMPANY_CD = LEFT(TABLE2.CMPNYID,  4)
                             AND USR = 'Badshah'
```

Comment: But this also can't use an index I think, and might not be substantially faster than the OP.

Comment: Try using **LEFT(TABLE2.CMPNYID,  4)** as i have edited the query above.

Comment: depends on the Db2 Platform and version...Db2 for IBM i would allow you to create a derived index on  LEFT(CMPNYID, 4).

Answer (score 0):

try with an exist :

```
SELECT f1.ELIG_TYP
FROM TABLE1 f1 
WHERE exists 
( 
   SELECT * FROM TABLE2 f2 
   WHERE f2.USR = 'Badshah' and substr(f2.CMPNYID, 1, 4)=f1.COMPANY_CD
)
```

or if you have still perf problem try may be this :

```
SELECT f1.ELIG_TYP
FROM TABLE1 f1 
WHERE exists 
( 
  SELECT * FROM TABLE2 f2 
  WHERE f2.USR = 'Badshah' and f2.CMPNYID like f1.COMPANY_CD || '%'
)
```